# how to run gather and a coroutine task concurrently

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio

I have approximately the following code

```
import asyncio
.
.
.
async def query_loop()
    while connected:
        result = await asyncio.gather(get_value1, get_value2, get_value3)
        if True in result:
            connected = False

async def main():
    await query_loop()

asyncio.run(main())
```

The get_value - functions query a device, receive values, and publish them to a server. If no problems occur they return False, else True.

Now I need to implement, that the get_value2-function checks if it received the value 7. In this case I need the program to wait for 3 min before sending a special command to the device. But in the mean time, and also afterwards the query_loop should continue.

Has anybody an idea how to do that ?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to modify `get_value2` so that it reacts to a value received from device by spawning additional work in the background, i.e. do something without the loop in `query_loop` having to wait for that new work to finish.

You can use `asyncio.create_task()` to spawn a background task. In fact, you can always combine `create_task()` and `await` to runs things in the background; `asyncio.gather` is just a utility function that does it for you. In this case `query_loop` remains unchanged, and `get_value2` gets modified like this:

```
async def get_value2():
    ...
    value = await receive_value_from_device()
    if value == 7:
        # schedule send_command() to run, but don't wait for it
        asyncio.create_task(special_command())
    ...
    return False

async def special_command():
    await asyncio.sleep(180)
    await send_command_to_device(...)
```

Note that if `get_value1` and others are async functions, the correct invocation of `gather` must call them, so it should be `await asyncio.gather(get_value1(), get_value2(), get_value3())` (note the extra parentheses).

Comment: ok thanks for your answer it was very helpful! But one last question: you never await the task "asyncio.create_task(special_command()). Are sheduled task executed automatically even if they are not called with await ?

Comment: @Art3mis Yes, that's what `create_task` does, you can think of it as "await in the background".

Comment: so now I have the problem, that the task special_command is invoked on every iteration of the loop. But i only need it to run once in a time..

Comment: @Art3mis `special_command` is only invoked when the value 7 is received from device. If you need to additionally restrict it by time, you can use a global variable (or any other shared-state variable) to prevent multiple `special_command`s from running at once. The answer was intended to show how to spawn a background task, not to cover all the minutiae of your use case.